# UIScrollView setContentOffset (Paging) stopped by touch screen

Tags: ios, pagination, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I am doing paging effect in UICollectionView. My solution is shown below.

`setContentOffset` method will be called in `scrollViewWillEndDragging` and calculate the next or previous page contentOffset x value and set it with animation.

However, there is one issue which is that once the `setContentOffset` function has been called, if I touch the screen, then the scrollView will be stopped. Even if you release your finger, it won't continue, which means it stops at a wrong position.

Actually, I've tried to override the `targetOffset` in `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` but this issue still exists. Also, I tried to call `touchesEnded` but this is not even triggered at all. Furthermore, I tried `isPagingEnabled` and it won't cause this issue but my collectionView items are more complicated, which leads to a wrong `targetContentOffset`.

My current solution is set `scrollView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false` after setContentOffset and set it back to true when `scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation` called. This is okay but I am still wondering if there is any good way to do this?

I tried both Google Calendar and Outlook, they will reset you back to the position it should be.

I searched online and I cannot find any questions regarding this issue.

Could you help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot to figure it out and finally, I got something correct to share with you guys.

The solution is to set `targetContentOffset` in `scrollviewWillEndDragging`, then I can get what I want.

The truth behind this is that if you call `setContentOffset`, then `scrollviewWillEndDragging` won't be called in the second time endDragging (when you touch the screen after the first endDragging). However, if you simply set `targetContentOffset = requiredContentOffset`, then the second time endDragging will be called and at this time, the paging method will be called again to navigate `UIScrollView` to a correct position.

What I've learned from this is never call `setContentOffset` when you do the pagination effect. Some tutorials online for the pagination are totally wrong.

Comment: Hey @jeff, I'm having exactly the same issue. Do you have some public code on github that shows your implementation?